# How to register the SIEBELHTMLLib for programing

Tags: visual-studio, siebel

I am making a program to access the CARMAN system. But when i compile the program it show me that missing the namespace SIEBELHTMLLib . So my question is how to register the SIEBELHTMLLib  and make it showing in the Visual Studio? And When can i download the setup file for SIEBELHTMLLib ?

Answer (score 0):

Install `Siebel` on the machine you are compiling `VB` program.

```
Application Name: SiebelHTML
Application ID: {253A9D17-F982-11D4-8BE4-00D0B7E61414}
```

You can get `'SiebelAx_Desktop_Integration_21225.exe'` from any machine which has `Siebel` application installed. Either register it manually or add a component reference to Visual Studio by providing location of file.